# Proving $\limsup (A_n) \cap \limsup (A^{c}_{n}) = \limsup (A_n \cap A^{c}_{n+1})$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\{A_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence in $\mathscr{F}$. Prove that $$\limsup (A_n) \cap \limsup (A^{c}_{n}) = \limsup (A_n \cap A^{c}_{n+1})$$

Since is an equality I have to show both inclusions.

Suppose  $x\in \limsup (A_n) \cap \limsup (A^{c}_{n})$.

According to the definition of limsup:

$x \in \limsup (A_n)$ $\dashrightarrow$ $\forall n \ge 1,  \ \exists k \ge n$ such that $ x \in A_{k}$

$x \in \limsup (A^{c}_n)$ $\dashrightarrow$ $\forall m \ge 1,  \ \exists h \ge m$ such that $ x \in A^{c}_{h}$

From here I don't know how to procede.

Comment: $B_n$ is not used anywhere?

Comment: you're right, i'll remove it.. it was used in a previous proof

Comment: That is fine, but what have you done so far? Where are you stuck? You can start from the definition of $\limsup$? Lastly, in the right hand side the index of one of the $A$ is $n$ and the other is $n+1$ : is this intended?

Comment: Yes it is intended, I edited the post with the few steps that I was able to take till now.

Comment: Show that any $x$ belonging to the left hand side also belongs to the right hand side. You have written the definition right : basically, for all $n \geq 1$, you have to show that there is $k \geq n$ such that $x \in A_k \cap A_{k_1}^c$, given what you wrote.

Comment: You've omitted the complement sign on the right hand side at the 2nd line

Comment: @Matematleta That's still incorrect.  See my comment below.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Yes. Thanks. I will modify the proof. I still think it can be done using pure set maipulations.

Comment: @Matematleta The problem is the second transition.  You'll need to recall the very definition of set unions and intersections to justify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a proof using events.

Borrow the notion "infinitely often" (i.o.) from Durrett's probability textbook (in the section on Borel-Cantelli's lemma), rewrite $\limsup$ as $i.o.$, and the reverse inclusion should be obvious.

$$\{A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c i.o.\} \subseteq \{A_n i.o.\}  \cap  \{A_n^c i.o.\}$$

Let $x\in\{A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c i.o.\}$ for any $n$, find $N\ge n$ so that $x\in A_N \cap A_{N+1}^c$.  This shows the $x \in \{A_n i.o.\}$.  Similarly, $x \in \{A_n^c i.o.\}$

---

Show the direct inclusion by contradiction.  Let $x \notin \{A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c i.o.\}$.  i.e.  $x \in A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c$ "finitely often".

Therefore, $x \in A_n^c \cup A_{n+1}$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Since $x \in \{A_n i.o. \}$, there exists a (larger) $N\ge n$ so that $x \in A_N$.  Invoke our assumption $x \in A_N^c \cup A_{N+1}$ to conclude that $ x\in A_{N+1}$.  Inductively, we've shown that $x \in A_m$ for all $m \ge N$, which contradicts $x \in \{A_n^c i.o.\}$.

Comment: I think you can do the second inclusion directly. Sketch: Fix $n$ and let $j$ be the least integer such that $x\in A_{j+1}^c$.Then, $x\notin A^c_j\Rightarrow x\in A_j\Rightarrow x \in A_j\cap A_{j+1}^c$.

Comment: @Matematleta Nice and concise.  Why don't you re-write your answer to include this set-theoretic approach aside from my probabilistic and intuitive one?

Comment: I will. And I just went through your (interesting) proof and am happy to upvote it.

Comment: @Matematleta Thank you for your appreciation of my proof.  You're right that a set-theoretic way is more direct.  However, it's equally pedagogic to present a probabilistic argument based on counting because it's more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the set-theoretic formulation: $\limsup A_n=\left ( \bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{j\ge n}A_j \right ).$ That is to say, $x\in \limsup A_n$ if and only if for all integers $n$ there is an integer $j\ge n$ such that $x\in A_j.$

So, suppose $x\in \limsup A_n\cap \limsup A_{n}^c.$ Fix $n$ and choose the least integer $j\ge n$ for which $x\in A^c_{j+1}.$ Then, $x\notin A_j^c\Rightarrow x\in A_j\Rightarrow x\in A_j\cap A^c_{j+1}$ and it follows that $x\in \limsup (A_n\cap A^c_{n+1}).$

On the other hand, if $x\in \limsup (A_n\cap A^c_{n+1})$, then for each integer $n$, there is an integer $j\ge n$ such that $x\in A_j\cap A^c_{j+1}$ and it follows that $x\in \limsup A_n\cap \limsup A_{n}^c$.