# First read for rigorous probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book for self-study of rigorous probability theory. I would like a book which is at a completly introductory level, but which is rigorously written. Especially not welcome are books like Introduction to Probability by Sheldon Ross ( which is a great book in its own right ).

The book should have as little assumptions as previous knowledge as possible.

Analog to the book I am looking for is something like Spivaks Calculus or Apostols Calculus but for probability theory.

I am really really stuck,since I suck at learning non-rigorous mathematics,and I always happen to land into some corner case when I try to apply it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn measure theory first. There's no way around it.

Comment: What path would you recommend ( as in books and in which order ) ? Thing is I really need it for application, but if it is laid out badly and slopy I cant connect the dots

Comment: If your goal is to apply, measure theory might not be such a good idea. Maybe have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977490/best-rigorous-probability-theory-textbook-without-measure-theory?rq=1

Comment: What I really deseprately need is rigorous treatment of conditional probabilities and Bayes theorem,everything else is not so urgent

Comment: @Math_QED Would you expect OP to understand the probabilistic meaning of the abstract σ-algebra from a real-analysis book (say, baby Rudin's intro to Lebesgue's theory of integration)?  An introductory textbook in probability theory is more appropriate to an undergrad who starts learning it.

Comment: I thought the OP has knowledge about probability. That's why he mentioned that Ross' book was good.

Comment: @Math_QED That's not a probability theory textbook, and it won't reveal the probabilistic meaning of objects in measure theory.

Comment: Ross is not a probability book???

Comment: @Math_QED From [Ross' book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=A3YpAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Introduction+to+Probability+ross&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji6oav08reAhWIbsAKHULdCMEQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false)'s preface and the section title "1.2 Sample Space and Events", it *seems* that it discusses probability theory.  However, if you bother to give it a read, you'll understand why OP *doesn't* want this book. "Any subset $E$ of the sample space $S$ is known as an event." (p.2)  This is acceptable for statistics undergrads, but that's *incompatible* with Kolmogorov's axioms for probability.

Comment: You are right. I didn't read the book, and that would be a  huge turn-off for me.

Comment: @Math_QED In fact, it's said in the preface that that book adopts a *nonrigorous* approach.  It's important to think "probabilistically". To illustrate what "probabilistically" means, consider a set-theoretic equality $$\limsup (A_n) \cap \limsup (A^{c}_{n}) = \limsup (A_n \cap A^{c}_{n+1}).$$ If considered set-theoretically, it's possible to end up with a [wrong answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtTS2.png). However, this equality holds intuitively if you think about the [events $\{A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c i.o.\}$,$\{A_n i.o.\}$ and $\{A_n^c i.o.\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2980623/290189).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85595/discussion-between-gnusupporter-8964--and-math-qed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good books on "advanced" probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156165/good-books-on-advanced-probabilities)

Answer (score 2):

You might try [K.L. Chung, "Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hDnnBwAAQBAJ), or [W. Feller, "An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sklznQAACAAJ).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Kai Lai Chung's [*Elementary Probability Theory with Stochastic Processes*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-9346-7).  The author was a reowned probabilist.  It's tailor made for undergraduates who wish to learn probability theory from scratch.  This books gives simple examples that have deep interpretations.